# How to use COM objects from dll in Qt with no registration

Tags: qt, com, activeqt

I have a COM visible dll with control which I need to use in my Qt Application (4.8.4).
Control code in c#

```
[Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")]
public class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        //Some code
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I use QAxWidget to call it like this

```
QAxWidget *myControl = new QAxWidget(centralWidget);
myControl ->setControl("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

But of course it wouldn't work as there is no information about my control in registry

I read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx, and it says this could be resolved through manifests, I tried the same for my Qt application and it doesnt work, it still says

```
CoCreateInstance failure (Class not registered)
```

Either I do not set manifest for Qt in the right way, or setControl() method always looks to the registry. How knows how to deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you register the control first, to test the Qt code, before trying to see if it works when the control is not registered, as suggested by the article ? And shouldn't the UUID be enclosed in {} ?

Comment: Yeah, I did, it perfectly works when I register it. The article stands only for bare C++ applications. Manifests work for it. But in Qt manifests work in some different way and Im not sure if this is going to help me